# Defining formBuilder formArray - TSLint error

Tags: angular, tslint

tslint give me errors for this code

```
 private createForm() {
    this.addNewUserForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: ["", Validators.required],
      firstName: ["", Validators.required],
      lastName: ["", Validators.required],
      userRole: this.formBuilder.array([]),
      userRoles: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });

    this.addNewUserForm.get("userRole") as FormArray,   // give me error for this line
      this.addNewUserForm.get("userRoles") as FormArray; // give me error for this line
  }
```

TSlint error

> unused expression, expected an assignment or function call

I get the same error when getting data from `@ngrx/store`

```
getListOfAllSponsors() {
     this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.SponsorsActions.LoadSponsors());
 }
```

What is good way to call this without tslint errors?
Thnx

Comment: What do you expect these 2 instructions to do? They get an unexisting control from the form group, and do absolutely nothing with it.

Comment: I forget to add another two line in createForm function... sry... When i create form i already have data for this two instructions... and on this way this working, and I get data properly in my form

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What's the point in getting a control out of the form group and doing nothing with it?

Comment: I remove it, I just start working on this code and I don't know why guy before me put it there.... What about this.store.dispatch? Thnx

Comment: I guess ignoring the return value is acceptable in this case, but I don't know ngrx very much.